# How do I get <jsp:include /> functionality in a standard class?

Tags: java, jsp

Background: Migrating an application from ball of mud to MVC.  Many classes contain HTML building methods.  Refactoring as I add features, I'm not looking for a complete rewrite.

I'd like to build some smaller views but need to render them in between some serious string building.

To compose my views is a jsp I would use `<jsp:include />` tags.  Is there similiar functionality I can call from a class?  I'm looking at java.net.URL but it will require a little plumbing.  The class already depends on the request object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you mean "call from a class". If your "class" is actually a [Servlet](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html), then you can get the [RequestDispatcher](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) from the servlet context, and call the `include()` method from it. If your class is called from a servlet, you can pass the RequestDispatcher into it.

But that's a really bad idea.

Based on your description, I'd think of using a [taglib](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/package-frame.html) for my "serious string handling", and invoke those tags from the view.

Comment: The Class is a POJO with an awesome getSomeSeriousHTML() method.  It's looks like an inside out jsp minus the Servlet interface.  Thanks and happy hunting.